# nullToken scope not set. This request does not have the required privilege

Tags: android, token, bucket

In the use of Autodesk's AndroidSDK, the token was successfully obtained; but at Create Bucket, unexpectedly returned “nullToken scope not set. This request does not have the required privilege.”
code:

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(BASEUrl+ upload_srv);
request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

//v2 changed the param name from 'policy' to 'policyKey'
String jsonstr  ="{\"bucketKey\":\""+ newBucketName + "\", \"servicesAllowed\":{}, \"policyKey\":\"temporary\"}";
HttpEntity jsonent = new StringEntity(jsonstr,HTTP.UTF_8);
request.setEntity(jsonent);

HttpClient httpclient =  getNewHttpClient();
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, globalcookies);

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request,localContext);
```